# SSR in Spartacus Storefront Message

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

I added SSR Support, but when I run the command: **npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr**, appears this message, anyone knows why?

[image: SSR Message]

Comment: Do you have any interaction with the DOM in your code? If you search the project for `Element` do you have any results? During SSR there is no DOM and other global objects as in the browser, see the guidelines:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-coding-guidelines/ and 
https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis

Answer (score 0):

In your local directories, open `/server/main.js` and navigate to line 1:4106087 (line 1 column 4106087). You should be able to exactly pinpoint where the error is being thrown.

Put a validation on every place you use `Element`, such as:

```
import {isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';

...

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: number) {}

if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    // Your code here where you access the DOM
}
...
```